# Broken partition after upgrade windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a big problem with my computer because I cannot access to my linux.
My computer is dual boot with windows 7 and ubuntu. When I upgrade to windows 10, I lost my grub dual boot.
To repair it, I used boot-repair-disk(https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-r … p_redirect). Boot is repaired but only for windows, grub having totally disappeared.
I have a 256GB SSD with 100GB for linux. My partition yet exists, I see it with fdisk but it appear that this partition is broken.
I try to use Gparted to repair my different partition but this program see nothing because overlapping problem etc

I give you the configuration of my computer generated with my usb boot-repair-disk :

https://paste.ubuntu.com/26334821/

Is it possible to restore grub and have a dual boot without formatting my linux partition ?

Thanks in advance.

Olivier.

Comment: I find that boot repair pretty much causes more problems than it solves. Your data is likely fine but just be cautious. Try out running testdisks "lost partitions" function: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: The error is apparently due to extended partitions as all of those are lost.

Comment: The remaining disk space after partition 3 is roughly 105GB (not GiB), i could guess you had 100GB Linux and a 5GB swap?

Comment: Yes I think i do a swap when I install linux

Comment: Seems to be related to this long standing Windows bug: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ab3374c2-dd2c-4607-865b-896b6fe0fd26/the-partition-that-hosts-windows-vista-may-disappear Based on your Boot repair log your extended partition is not 1MB aligned which is what trips up that bug. However I wouldn't have expected it to still affect Windows 10.

Comment: Run this command:
`(for b in {293689342..293689442}; do (echo $b; blkid -p -O "$(($b * 512))" /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Crucial_CT256M550SSD3_14280DBE2A46); done) | tee fssearchlog.txt`
And post the log file here.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EunyYUUi

Comment: I would have expected that to have found something. Lets start it at the end of sda3 and search 10MiB.

`(for b in {293687295..293707775}; do (echo $b; blkid -p -O "$(($b * 512))" /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Crucial_CT256M550SSD3_14280DBE2A46); done) | tee fssearchlog.txt`

Comment: I finally reinstall my linux partition because it was urgent.
Thank you for your help